# Finitary Alternating Groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

If $X$ is an infinite set, then the finitary alternating group on $X$ can be defined in the following equivalent ways:

1. the group of all even permutations on $X$ under composition
2. the kernel of the sign homomorphism on the finitary symmetric group on $X$. (see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitary_alternating_group))

First, what does even permutation mean if $X$ is infinite? Second, how does one construct the homomorphism mentioned in statement 2.? For example, if $X = \{1,...,n\} \times \Bbb{N}$, what does finitary alternating symmmetric mean in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The finitary symmetric group is the group of all permutations with *finite support,* or said in another way: An element in the finitary symmetric group of a set is a permtutation that permutes only finitely many elements of the set. You can then define the sign to be the sign of the permutation restricted to the support, which is a permutation of a finite set.

For $X= \{1,...,n\} \times \mathbb{N}.$ If $\tau$ is a finitary symmetric permuatation, then there is a finite subset $A$ of $X, $ such that for all $(a,b) \in X-A, \tau(a,b) = (a,b)$